# Avoid splash screen activity when pressing Back button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

In my application, I have two activities. First is a splash screen, which simply shows the application name and few other info.

Upon clicking on the splash screen activity, I'm loading the main activity. My app works fine, but I'm facing a small issue. If I press back button from my main activity, control is going to splash screen activity. But I don't want to show the splash screen activity again, I want to avoid splash screen activity when pressing Back button.

Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in your splash screen `<activity>`.

Comment: Thanks, could you add a little description to your answer?

Comment: 1. use launchmode : singleTask, 2. use noHistory, 3. when opening any activity from splash screen, call finish() after call, 4. when opening any activity from splash screen addFlags NEW_TASK, and CLEAR_TASK Inent flags in those intents.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, you want the splash activity to not show after changing activity. You should note activities save On Stack and with starting new activity push on it and with finish you pop on top stack. I think that if you the call `finish()` method your problem fix as in your splash screen activity where you call StartActivity insert `finish()` after

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Splash.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Hope to be useful :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just call

```
finish();
```

In your Splash screen when you jump to the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, you should note
that:

1: by calling the finish() method, the Splash activity
will close after execution, meaning that it will not be
available in the stack.

```
@Override
protected    void    onCreate(Bundle saveInstsnceState){
super.onCreate( saveInstanceState);

\\ do something here
Intent    intentSplash    =    new Intent(SplashActivity.this,    NextActivity.class);
StartActivity(intentSplash);
finish ();
}
```

You will achieve your aim using the method above
but...

2: If you want to prevent your users from force
exiting the app  (pressing back button) while the
splash activity in still ongoing which is the best
practice in android, then you need to call the
onBackPressed () method.

```
Class NoBackSplash{

@Override
protected    void    onCreate(Bundle saveInstsnceState){

super.onCreate( saveInstanceState);
\\ do something here
Intent    intentSplash    =    new Intent(SplashActivity.this,    NextActivity.class);
StartActivity(intentSplash);
finish ();
}

@Override
public  void  OnBackPressed(){

};

}
```

With this OnBackPressed() method, your splash activity will not be force to exit no matter how hard the user try.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, you want the splash activity to not show when you click on back button. First of all you should know that all the activities on android are in form of **STACK**. So what we need we just end the splash activity after it execute. we can do this by calling **finish()** method in android studio. here is the solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, home.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Handler hd = new Handler();
    hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
           

              #by calling finish() method,splash activity will close after execution

              finish();
        }
    },3000);


}}
```